# flutter generic subtype restrictions

Tags: flutter, generics

how I can say to my generic flutter class/extension

```
extension BetweenIterable<T> on Iterable<T>
```

what my function should have type `R` where `T extends R`

```
Iterable<R> addBetween<R, T extends R>(final List<R> list)
```

I try this variant, but flutter think `T` is new type (not related to extension type), and I have error.

> The element type 'T' can't be assigned to the list type 'R'.

Finally I try do something like this.

```dart
extension BetweenIterable<T> on Iterable<T> {
  Iterable<R> addBetween<R, T extends R>(final List<R> list) {
    return expandIndexed((index, element) {
      return [element, if (length > index + 1) ...list];
    });
  }
}
```

it all for be able do this for example

```dart
class WidgetA extends Widget {};
class WidgetB extends Widget {};

final List<WidgetA> listAWidgets = [WidgetA(1), WidgetA(2)];

final List<Widget> extended = listAWidgets.addBetween<Widget>([
   WidgetB('text'),
)]
```

Comment: Do not use images, copy your code and the error message.

Comment: Also, could you explain what is your purpose of this extensions? Seems you're having a trouble on something that should not exists.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to say is that your `R` type must be a subtype of `T`, not inverse.

```dart
// [Text] is a subclass of [Widget]
final List<Text> listAWidgets = [
  Text('WidgetA is of type Text'),
  Text('WidgetA is of type Text')
];

// Then cast it as a list of [Widget].
final List<Widget> listWidgets = listAWidgets.cast<Widget>();

// The super class of [Icon] and [Text] is [Widget]
// but the [listAWidgets] is not of type [Widget] but [Text]
// You need first cast [listAWidgets] to a list of [Widget]
// To allow include [Icon]s.
// You can also simply declare
// [listAWidgets] variable as a List of [Widget] instead of [Text]
final List<Widget> extended = listWidgets.addBetween<Widget>(
  [const Icon(Icons.add)],
).toList();
```

And even if you mean to, it's not allowed because we have no way to say a List of type `T` is of type `R` that you received on the function type arg.

Usage:

```dart
print(<num>[1, 2, 3].addBetween([0.0, 0])); // [1, 0.0, 0, 2, 0.0, 0, 3]
```

In Flutter:

```dart
// [Text] is a subclass of [Widget]
final List<Text> listAWidgets = [
  Text('WidgetA is of type Text'),
  Text('WidgetA is of type Text')
];

// [Text] is a subclass of [Widget]
final List<Widget> listWidgets = listAWidgets.cast<Widget>();

// The super class of [Icon] and [Text] is [Widget]
// but the [listAWidgets] is not of type [Widget] but [Text]
// You need first cast [listAWidgets] to a list of [Widget]
// To allow include [Icon]s.
// You can also simply declare
// [listAWidgets] variable as a List of [Widget] instead of [Text]
final List<Widget> extended = listWidgets.addBetween<Widget>(
  [const Icon(Icons.add)],
).toList();
```

The name of this operation (add elements between each element of a list) is called **intersperse**.

You can find some other implementations:

- https://github.com/modulovalue/dart_intersperse.
- https://github.com/Innim/dart_list_extensions#iterables.

Comment: in your case in return we still have T, but I need R on return

Comment: Then you want 2 operations at once: add the element, and cast the list. Updated the snippet.

Comment: I don't need cast, I need restriction for generic for check it by flutter on compile step , I don't want runtime error

Comment: try your answer on my example with `WidgetA` and `WidgetB`, `WidgetA` not extend `WidgetB`, they both extend `Widget`

Comment: That's why you need to cast them, you cannot add `WidgetB` to a list of `WidgetA` simply because A is not B. If you know they both have a super class **W**, then first cast your WidgetA list to W, then add the WidgetB elements to it.

Comment: Added further explanation to why you first need to cast, Dart cant imply B have the same super type of A. I agree would be nice if so. But unfortunately it doesn't. So, from the snippet you provided, this is the only solution I found.